# How Do i trigger a CRM plugin from a look up Value change

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dataverse

I have a plugin with a registered step on opportunity table using the create message. The execution stage is pre validation. However the plugin is only triggered when I click the actual save button. Is there a way to trigger it when I change say the account look field on the opportunity form in CRM?

I created the plugin and  set the filtering attribute on the accountid attribute. I expected when the account selection changes, the plugin will be triggered, but it did not. switching to update message also requires I actually click the save button before the plugin is triggered.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you should use the onchange event in JS not a plugin. The plugin is designed for backend events.

Comment: Or you could use a Business Rule, depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: Ok, thank you. I taught Plugin was a one stop shop to handle every extension you need in the system.

Comment: @jasonscript , well i want to retrieve the currency value of a selected account on an opportunity form in CRM and set it as the value for Currency field for the opportunity. I doubt a business rule can handle that?

Comment: PreValidation is an event run first *after* you invoke record create (or update). In your scenario you must use frontend libraries (JS).